# Best & easiest way to do my UX for iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, viewcontroller, user-experience

I'm a newbies in iOS application dev and I am confronted with a simple problem!

Since the picture speaks louder than words, please find attached a small screenshot/mockup of what I would do (the easiest way and best way to do)!

So to explain, I wish my "HomeViewController" measures about half of my screen, and the other half would be dedicated to 3 others viewController (First, Second and ThirdViewController).

To access these three viewControllers (as you see in the picture), there are three button on the "HomeViewController"

My problem is quite simple, I'm looking for the best and easiest way to do this !

I hope you understand me because I'm French ;-)

[**CLICK HERE TO SEE MY UX PROJECT MOCKUP** http://imageshack.us/a/img801/5422/o6o.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img801/5422/o6o.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your problem. Now I think the way you choose to implement make more complicate like you create HomeViewController or ThirdViewController.

My sugesstion : Now you have a viewController that self.view . instead of creating HomeViewController or ThirdViewController, you just should create HomeView or ThirdView (it's just UIView). After that , you add HomeView in a half of screen on sef.view , add 3 buttons in HomeView . in every button have a function when you click, you just change view(First, Second and ThirdView) by remove old view before create and add new view.

Let's me know if you don't understand. I thinks this is simple if you choose simple way.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a Master Detail Application which is a basic template available within Xcode from the new projects chooser. Apple recommends that you not duplicate functionality, but instead use the standard functionality of UIKit. The idea is to get out of the way of the user's content by giving them handles that they are familiar with. Look into tutorials showing how to use tableViews and the Master Detail Application template.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how in depth you would like to get, but the easiest layout in my mind would be a single view controller with three seperate views that can be added/removed from that view controller.  Create your three buttons with each button having a different selector attached to it (something like "showViewOne, showViewTwo, showViewThree, etc.  If you wanted to get fancy you could point them all to the same function and then do a conditional statement on the sender inside that function).  The in the three functions show the new view you want to display and remove the other two (if they are present).

I can get more in depth and possibly add code tomorrow if you need, but it seems pretty straight forward.